The impact of Async Sampling on recording JPA and HTTP Server views during stress tests with JProfiler
Our team is currently running stress tests and using JProfiler for monitoring.
We’ve noticed that when the number of concurrent threads goes up, not only does CPU usage spike, but the time it takes for WAITING threads to execute SQL statements in JPA views also increases. So, we decided to record both JPA views and HTTP Server views.
Since Full Sampling significantly affects the target server’s performance, we looked into the official documentation and switched to Async Sampling to see if it helps clarify the issue.

JProfiler Help - Method call recording (ej-technologies.com)

Can we ask if Async Sampling is the right way of sampling for this kind of stress test? Will it impact the two views we’re currently recording?
Thanks!
We have already referred to the official documentation, but we are still not very sure.


Since Full Sampling significantly affects the target server’s performance,

With Java 17+ there is no significant difference from Async sampling, so I would recommend to use full sampling. See
https://www.ej-technologies.com/blog/2024/02/why-jvmti-sampling-is-better-than-async-sampling-on-modern-jvms/

We are using Java 8 and do not plan to upgrade to Java 17+ at the moment. Could you please provide information regarding the situation in a Java 8 environment?

With Java 8, you can indeed use Async Sampling for low overhead.
